# What if debezium source connector of kafka connect fails to produce to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I use debezium source connector for connecting mongoDB with SMT and AvroConverter.

When facing serialization error due to compatibility, does the connector skip the error records, or it retries sending the error record?

I set `error.tolerance = 'all'` (should be`errors.tolerance = 'all'`). I think the connector does not commit the offset back to kafka so the connector keeps retrying sending the record, am I right?

Comment: Do you mean `errors.tolerance`?

Comment: Can you explain about "committing the offset back to kafka"?

Comment: When the records arrive kafka, the position of the oplog is commited to kafka?

Comment: > The Kafka Connect framework automatically commits offsets to the topic configured by the offset.storage.topic property. When a Connect worker or task is restarted, it can use the task’s SourceTaskContext to obtain an OffsetStorageReader, which has an offset method for getting the latest offset recorded for a given source partition. The task can then use the offset and partition information to resume importing data from the source without duplicating or skipping records. ([Source](https://www.confluent.jp/blog/create-dynamic-kafka-connect-source-connectors/))

Comment: Also check https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#what_happens_when_debezium_stops_or_crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can configure behaviour of retries, e.g.:

```
# retry for at most 10 minutes times waiting up to 30 seconds between consecutive failures
errors.retry.timeout=600000
errors.retry.delay.max.ms=30000
```

If the retry limit for a failure is reached, then the tolerance limit is used to determine if this record should be skipped (`errors.tolerance=all`), or if the task is to be killed (`errors.tolerance=none`).

More details in the [**KIP-298**: Error Handling in Connect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect).